# Django Error reporting with Custom send_email

Tags: python, django, django-settings, error-reporting, django-errors

I kindly need your help to make django error reports by email.

I use service account with Gmail API to authorize and send emails.

How can this work with default django error reporting send_email.

I know I have to add the below to the settings and debug must be false:

ADMINS, MANAGERS, SERVER_EMAIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to send without setting up backend email.

1. I setup the handlers in settings.
2. Created CustomAdminHandler.py and override send_mail with my own sending email function.

Never thought its that simple.

Comment: Can you provide more details please? Some illustrations would help.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a email handling backend (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#smtp-backend for a SMTP email, or https://github.com/dolfim/django-gmailapi-backend/blob/master/gmailapi_backend/mail.py for an example of configuring the Gmail API as an `EmailBackend`).

Then set up an `AdminEmailHandler` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler) to log error messages using the `EmailBackend` you set up.

Comment: I have setup all of the above, tested the email backend it works. However, error emails is not being sent. Knowing I added the mail handler and mentioned my custom email backend.